# Use scss with react-frame-component in create-react-app

Tags: webpack, sass, create-react-app, craco, react-frame-component

We have a create-react-app that uses the **react-frame-component** to render one part of the page completely independent of the rest of the page.

We have been using css files within the frame to apply styles to the components.
This can be done by supplying the initialContent-property with -tags for the css files to the Frame-component, like this (taken from https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component/issues/74#issuecomment-347710246)

```
import Frame from 'react-frame-component'
import styles from 'public/css/styles.iframe.css'

const initialContent = () => {
  return (
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="${styles}" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page" class="page"></div>
      </body>
    </html>`
  )
}

<Frame initialContent={initialContent()}>
  <FrameContent />
</Frame>
```

Now we'd like to be able to use scss files as well.

The problem is when importing the scss files in the app they will be applied to the parent frame and not to the inner frame (of course), no matter in which component you import them.

So what we'd need would be a way to trigger the compilation of the scss file and get the path to the compiled css returned which we could then supply as a string to the Frame-component (like we do with css-files already).

We're already using craco to overwrite some of the cra-config.

So I thought about applying a scss compiler plus a file-loader for certain suffixed scss files.

Here is my craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(s*).theme.scss$/,
            use: [
              "file-loader",
              "sass-loader"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And the file is in

```
css/style.theme.scss
```

It's included like this:

```
const testScss = require("./css/style.theme.scss");
```

But I keep getting

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './css/style.theme.scss' in '.../.../dist'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Matthias?

Answer (score 0):

In order to load `scss` files you will need `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader`. Following rule works perfectly for me. You can give it a try.

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    use: [
      { loader: "style-loader" },
      { loader: "css-loader" },
      { loader: "sass-loader" },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: This will work in the standard use-case, where you just want to compile the scss to css and apply it to the head (which we do already for the rest of the application, except the iframe).

But unfortunately that does not cover the special case with the iframe, where I need the path to the compiled css-file and supply that to the iframe-component instead of attaching it to the parent-frame (which your config would do).